# Improvements to "limit login attempts" plugin

Tags: login, limit

I'm new in php so I'm still not good enough to make improvements in this php file
This php file sends mail alerts to the site admin, I want to change it.

1. I want to add my email instead of admin email

it seems to be this line 556

```
    ` $admin_email = is_limit_login_multisite() ? get_site_option('admin_email') : get_option('admin_email');

@wp_mail($admin_email, $subject, $message); `
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts/

Comment: This appears to be 2, not 1 question, this is a Q&A site not a discussion forum, ask each question separately. Click the edit button and remove one, then put it in a new question using the ask question link in the top menu

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line:

```
$admin_email = is_limit_login_multisite() ? get_site_option('admin_email') : get_option('admin_email');
```

with : `$admin_email = 'your.email@yourdomain.com'`

But I don't recommend hardcoding the email address.